# Gparted error -- now disk disappeared

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, linux-mint, gparted

I tried to resize my 3TB internal HDD with gparted and it would just hang about halfway through.  So I instead tried to reformat the entire drive to ext4 using GParted.  I deleted it, then allocated two partitions and hit apply.  It seemed to get through the delete and writing the big partition, but it popped an error on the small partition.  I got in a loop of Ignore Retry Cancel so I restarted.  When it came back up, gparted can no longer see the drive -- and fdisk can't either.

Everything is connected correctly and there is plenty of power.  I'm using Linux Mint Live from a USB stick currently (this whole operation was from me deleting ubuntu and installing Mint)

Comment: Can you see the drive in your BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: No, in BIOS, it shows only two SATAs, my SSD and my DVD player.  No sign of the 3TB HDD

Comment: My answer to your comment got me wondering why even the bios couldn't see a connected something.  I opened it up and reseated/reconnected it and it popped up.  Weird as I never touched the case, just messed around in gparted.  If you toss in an answer, I can mark it correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Not really deserved, you did the work yourself :) Glad you've sorted it though.

Comment: 'Plenty of power'... lol

Comment: I meant as far as the power supply :)  I've seen some comments on similar threads having the user check to make sure their power supply is enough to power their HDD.